# Remove 1px under navigationBar without removing barTintColor

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to remove the 1px from the navigationBar and apply a white barTintColor, However when using below code in viewDidLoad it seem to remove not only the 1px bottomborder, but also remove the white barTintColor ?

```
//NavigationBar Style
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```